# Is rebinding a graphics pipeline in Vulkan a guaranteed no-op?

Tags: c++, vulkan

In the simplified scenario where each object to be rendered is translated into a secondary command buffer and each of those command buffers bind a graphics pipeline initially: is a guaranteed no-op to bind the pipeline that was immediately bound before? Or the order of execution of the secondary command buffers is not guaranteed at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is a guaranteed no-op to bind the pipeline that was immediately bound before?

No. In fact, in the case you're outlining, you should assume precisely the *opposite*. Why?

Since each of your CBs is isolated from the others, the `vkCmdBindPipeline` function has no way to know what was bound beforehand. Remember: the state of a command buffer that has started recording is *undefined*. Which means that the command buffer building code cannot make any assumptions about any state which you did not set within this CB.

In order for the driver to implement the optimization you're talking about, it would have to, at `vkCmdExecuteCommands` time, introspect into each secondary command buffer and start ripping out anything that is duplicated across CB boundaries.

That *might* be viable if `vkCmdExecuteCommands` has to copy all of the commands out of secondary CBs into primary ones. But that would only be reasonable for systems where secondary CBs don't exist at a hardware level and thus have to be implemented by copying their commands into the primary CB. But even in this case, implementing such culling would make the command take longer to execute compared to simply copying some tokens into the primary CB's storage.

When dealing with a low-level API, do not assume that the driver is going to use information outside of its immediate purview to optimize your code. *Especially* when you have the tools for doing that optimization yourself.

This is (yet another) a reason why you should not give each individual object its own CB.

> Or the order of execution of the secondary command buffers is not guaranteed at all?

The order of execution of commands is unchanged by their presence in CBs. However, the well-defined nature of the state these commands use *is* affected.

Outside of state inherited by secondary CBs, every secondary CB's state begins undefined. That's *why* you have to bind a pipeline for each one. Commands that rely on previously issued state only have well-defined behavior if that previously issued state is within the CB containing that command (or is inherited state).

Comment: Command buffers don't inherit any state. As Nicolas noted, that's why You need to set state in each command buffer separately. What's more, as far as I understand, primary command buffer's state after execution of a secondary command buffer is also undefined (only render pass and subpass state is preserved). So in such case You need to set state one again if You want to draw anything after executing a secondary command buffer.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: "*Command buffers don't inherit any state.*" Secondary command buffers *can* inherit *certain* state; hence the `VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo` object. For example, those intended to be used within a renderpass inherit the current renderpass's state. They can also inherit query state (given the appropriate feature).

Comment: True but those are only exceptions for the general rule. But thanks for reminding this.

Comment: Some GPUs may skip work associated with redundant pipeline binds, so in practice the cost may only be in CPU time to write the command buffer and time in the GPU frontend to fetch the command buffer and realize that it's redundant. But that's definitely not guaranteed to be true across all implementations.