# Update push constant in primary command buffer but use in secondary?

Tags: vulkan

I have multiple secondary command buffers which are responsible for different geometry rendering. But the camera matrix obviously should stay the same. I wanted to update the camera matrix through push constants but I can't understand - should I do it for every secondary command buffer or I can do it only once - in the primary command buffer?

On one side push constants are the part of the pipeline state (specified in pipeline state layout) which is not inherited by secondary command buffers. But on the other side, there's a so-called "Pipeline Layout Compatibility", which I do not fully understand, but looks like it allows to update push constant once and use the updated values in subsequent commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (as You have noted) **state is not inherited between command buffers**. This means that You need to setup state (that is relevant for drawing or compute operations) in each command buffer separately. There are some exceptions to this rule but they are not connected with the problem You are talking about here.

So **yes, You need to set values of push constants in each command buffer separately**.

As for *pipeline layout compatibility* You are referring to, this means that when You set some pipeline state for a given pipeline and then when You bind another pipeline with a *compatible layout*, You don't have to set the same state again. It is preserved between pipelines with *compatible layouts*. So again, yes, You can *"update push constant once and use the updated values in subsequent commands"*. **But this must happen in the same command buffer.** You can use updated values in the pipelines bound to the same command buffer. But if You are in another command buffer, You need to setup relevant state once again. What's more - after You execute secondary command buffers from a primary command buffer, You need to set state in this primary command buffer once again too. In other words, primary command buffer forgets its state after executing secondary command buffers.

Comment: Thank you. In other words, if I have 1000 draw calls in 1000 secondary command buffers, I need to update push constants 1000 times, consuming the precious bandwidth? Just curious, why is it done like that? For me, it looks like that the implementation could know that the constant is set and allow to reuse it.

Comment: @nikitablack because pushconstants are expected to be different for each draw call, if you want a value to remain constant across draws then use a UBO/SSBO with a descriptor set.

Comment: @nikitablack Each command buffer is a separate entity. It is individual and independent from all other command buffers (that just how graphics hardware works, AFAIK). When You record vkCmdPushConstant() function, it stores small amount of data directly in the command buffer. So when You execute another command buffer (a secondary command buffer), it doesn't have access to the data of the primary command buffer.

Comment: @ratchetfreak And here again we have an inheritance problem - I'd have to bind UBO multiple times - in every secondary command buffer.

Comment: @nikitablack You need to do it nevertheless (no matter if You use push constants or descriptor sets). Or You can try not using secondary command buffers and do everything from primary command buffers.

Comment: @nikitablack: The problem is that you're not doing enough work in a secondary command buffer. You should not have just one draw call (for just one model/object) in a single secondary command buffer.

Comment: @NicolBolas there's another work of course - binding buffers, pipeline, setting viewport etc. In my case, all this work serves only one purpose - to draw a geometry. That's why I mentioned only draw calls commands. And basically, in my question, I asked about the possibility to put something on GPU once and reuse it. IIRC in DirectX12, I can have a virtual address in GPU which I can use to tell commands where to look for the data.

Comment: @nikitablack: That's my point: a single CB should not be about drawing "a" geometry; it should be about drawing "lots of" geometry. If the number of secondary CBs you create is proportional to the number of objects you draw, you're using the API incorrectly.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's interesting, I don't remember I saw this recomendation before. What are the reasons behind that and can you please provide links to read more about this?

Comment: @nikitablack: Well [there's the overhead of having thousands of state changes that accomplish little.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49985913/734069)